# ImageView not rotating

Tags: java, android, imageview

`ImageView` is not rotating ?

```
ImageView arrow1;
arrow1  =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow1);
Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
mtx.postRotate(90);
arrow1.setImageMatrix(mtx);
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Check This: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-image-rotate-example I think it may help you

Answer (score 0):

Now Image rotating

```
arrow1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow1);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.arrow1);
bmpWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
bmpHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
float curScale = 1F;        
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(curScale, curScale);
matrix.postRotate(90);  
if(resizedBitmap!=null){
 resizedBitmap.recycle();
}
resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, matrix, true);
arrow1.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
```